# Change a table of totals to a table of percentages based on total row

Tags: r, percentage

I have data like this:

```
a <- data.frame("Color" = c("Blue", "Red", "Green", "Total"),
                "N_Likes" = c(5, 4, 1, 10),
                "N_Dislikes" = c(2, 4, 2, 8))
```

Looks like this:

```
  Color N_Likes N_Dislikes
1  Blue       5          2
2   Red       4          4
3 Green       1          2
4 Total      10          8
```

This data is totals and I want to convert it into percentages.

I want to convert it into something like this:

```
  Color N_Likes N_Dislikes
1  Blue       50%          25%
2   Red       40%          50%
3 Green       10%          25%
4 Total      100%          100%
```

Where each value in the table is the percent based off of the total.
I know I could go through manually and do this but is there a way to easily make this change?

**UPDATE**

Also, if there are NA values I would like to ignore and leave those alone:

```
  Color N_Likes N_Dislikes  N_Neutral
1  Blue       5          2          1
2   Red       4          4         NA
3 Green       1          2          2
4 Total      10          8          3
```

Would result in:

```
  Color   N_Likes   N_Dislikes   N_Neutral
1  Blue       50%          25%      33.33%
2   Red       40%          50%          NA
3 Green       10%          25%      66.66%
4 Total      100%          100%       100%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through the numeric columns with `lapply`

```
col_idx <- sapply(a, is.numeric) # find positions of numeric columns
a[, col_idx] <- lapply(a[, col_idx], function(x) {
  ifelse(is.na(x), NA, paste0(x / max(x, na.rm = TRUE) * 100, "%"))
})
a
#  Color N_Likes N_Dislikes
#1  Blue     50%        25%
#2   Red     40%        50%
#3 Green     10%        25%
#4 Total    100%       100%
```

Comment: What if there is an NA value in the chart? How would you leave those as NA?

Comment: @Bear Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative `dplyr` solution:

```
a <- data.frame("Color" = c("Blue", "Red", "Green", "Total"),
                "N_Likes" = c(5, 4, 1, 10),
                "N_Dislikes" = c(2, 4, 2, 8))

library(dplyr)

a %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("N")), ~paste0(round(100*./last(.), 2), "%"))

#     Color N_Likes N_Dislikes
#   1  Blue     50%        25%
#   2   Red     40%        50%
#   3 Green     10%        25%
#   4 Total    100%       100%
```

I'm using `last(.)` under the assumption that `Total` will always be in the last row of your data frame.

For the case of `NA` you can use:

```
a %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("N")), 
                ~ifelse(is.na(.), "NA", paste0(round(100*./last(.), 2), "%")))
```

if you want to have `"NA"` (character value), or you can use:

```
a %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("N")), 
                ~ifelse(is.na(.), NA, paste0(round(100*./last(.), 2), "%")))
```

of you want to have a proper `NA` (missing value; not a string "NA")

Comment: You could shorten your answer using `paste0` in `~paste0(round(100*./last(.), 2), "%")`

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~sprintf("%3.0f%%", .x / .x[length(.x)] * 100))
#  Color N_Likes N_Dislikes
#1  Blue     50%        25%
#2   Red     40%        50%
#3 Green     10%        25%
#4 Total    100%       100%
```

---

To address the revised data with `NA`s

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~if_else(!is.na(.x), sprintf("%3.0f%%", .x / .x[length(.x)] * 100), "NA"))
```